# How to redirect one URL to a different directory (outside of DOCKER) using apache2

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have `example.com` which is an wordpress site installed **inside docker**, and I also have CI project stored in `/var/www/store`. I want user to be redirected to `/var/www/store` **(outside docker)** when entering `example.com/store` in address bar. This is my attempt.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
  RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-SSL" expr=%{HTTPS}
  ServerAdmin kontak@japati.net
  ServerName example.com
  ProxyRequests Off

  <Location />
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8100/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8100/
  </Location>
  
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/store(.*)$ /var/www/store$1 [L]

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /opt/acme-cert/example.com/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/acme-cert/example.com/site.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /opt/acme-cert/example.com/fullchain.cer

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But this doesn't work, I get page not found error from wordpress. I also tried `alias /store /var/www/store` but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to mix Docker with Apache, but right now **ALL** requests are getting forwarded to port 8100, which means obviously `RewriteRule`s aren't going to help. (They'll get forwarded too.) (Anyways, you can't use RewriteRule to go to a physical location, only to a URL.)

Your  block is forwarding ALL requests to port 8100. Let's fix that:

You'll want to add this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

  #.......Stuff.......
  Alias /store "/var/www/store" #<---------------- map "/store" to /var/www/store
  ProxyPass /store ! #<-------------- Place this before any other ProxyPass declarations
  <Location />
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8100/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8100/
  </Location>
```

Or you could instead do this:

```
  #.......Stuff.......
  Alias /store "/var/www/store" #<---------------- map "/store" to /var/www/store
  <Location /store>
    ProxyPass !
  </Location>
  <Location />
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8100/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8100/
  </Location>
```

Comment: I get this error `ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch can not have a path when defined in a location.`

Comment: @Liso Whoops. Edited. (You should also be able to alternatively create a new `<Location /store/> ProxyPass !</Location>` block BEFORE the other `<Location>`, but this ought to work too.)